# Best method for automating bulk file download

Tags: php, curl, cron, segmentation-fault, download

I am attempting to create a cron job that downloads image files that are stored in a queue in our database.

All of the functions that we are using work properly when run on our web server, however when I run the cron job using the following command: `php index.php cron image_download` I receive a `Segmentation Fault` error.

Debugging the cron job shows that this error occurs when the data is passed to the get_url_content function, which is called here:

```
foreach($urls as $url){

    $content = $this->get_url_content($url); 
}
```

And the function is here:

```
function get_url_content($url){
    $agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    return curl_exec($ch);
}
```

Is there a better way to download these files? Is it likely that a different method would not cause the same segmentation fault error? Thank you!

UPDATE: It appears that various methods I am trying are continually causing issues.  I am seeing either "Segmentation Fault" or "Killed" errors returned from the cron job.  Someone recommended that I look into using [Iron.io](http://iron.io) for this so I am going to check that out.  If anyone has other recommendations for how to manage this best I would appreciate additional information, thanks.

Comment: also please explain your command `php index.php cron image_download` that is `php index.php arg1 arg2`. `argv[0]` will be `index.php`, `argv[1]` will be `arg1`... so on.

Comment: Cool thanks for the answers so far...something is screwy with my localhost configuration and I am unable to run cron jobs on my localhost, so I have to test these in a live server environment.  I have not done so yet but will tomorrow.

Comment: Is the issue with cron not woeking, or does the php scipt `php index.php cron image_download` itself doesn't work? How are *All of the functions that you are using work properly when run on your web serve*`?

Comment: The cron doesn't work, it returns a "segmentation fault".  When I run the function fro a web browser it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach, but before that, are you giving it the full URL?

```
function get_content($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return($result);
}

function save_content($text,$new_filename){
    $fp = fopen($new_filename, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $text);
    fclose($fp);
}

// replace this with your array of urls from the database (make sure it is an array)
$urls = ['http://domain.com/path/to/file.zip', 'http://another.com/path/to/image.img'];

foreach($urls as $url){
    $new_filename = basename($url);
    $temp = get_content($url);
    save_content($temp,$new_filename);
}
```

This would get the file contents via its complete url and save it to disk, thus the being downloaded.

---

If you are not limited to curl, you may try something like:

```
$urls = ['http://domain.com/path/to/file.zip', 'http://another.com/path/to/image.img'];

foreach($urls as $url){
    $new_filename = basename($url);
    // or fopen can be file_get_contents: file_get_contents($url)
    file_put_contents($new_filename, fopen($url, 'r'));
}
```

or even

```
foreach($urls as $url){
    $new_filename = basename($url);
    shell_exec("wget $url -O $new_filename");
}
```

Comment: Alright, so it looks like I've discovered a structural issue with the way that I was calling these functions.  This answer has been helpful in getting me there, so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use curl option `CURLOPT_FILE` to download the file directly into the file from curl. For this case I have commented out two other options from your existing code. Here is your modified function:

```
function get_url_content($url, $file){
    $fp = fopen ($file, 'w+');                   // open file handle

    $agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);          // output to file
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);  // handle redirect
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_exec($ch);
    fclose($fp);                                  // closing file handle
}
```

Notice, I have added second parameter(file name as `$file`) with the function. So just pass your url and the file path(of course absolute path) to it.

If you are fluent at `Shell scripting`, you can use the curl's commandline option to download the files as well. For example this command will download the image into a designated file.

```
curl -s -L "http://img_url/" -o /var/path/image.jpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent a long time faffing around with alternative ways to do this sort of multifile download before working out that a straightforward solution is to use zipArchive. This allows you to create and open a zip file, add files to it, and close it. You can then create a weblink to the archive.